# Trying to patch k10 optimized zen kernel, getting invalid option

Tags: kernel, patch

Hi this is my first try on askubuntu, i hope you can understand what i say

here's the thing, I'm trying to patch a kernel, but patch says i put an invalid option in, which i have no idea where it is or what it is

```
    root@guilherme-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/usr/src/zen-kernel-3.14-master# patch -p1 home/guilherme/Downloads/kernel-314-gcc49-0.patch -march=amdfam10

    patch: invalid option -- 'a'
    patch: Try 'patch --help' for more information.
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following to get this done? From where did you get the command to patch?

Answer (score 0):

Check the command usage is correct! Is the option "-march" available with the version of the patch command you are running ?

Generally used as follows:

patch -p1 <  [/path/to/patch/file]

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt